# How to read xml string from a model in Razor

Tags: c#, xml, razor

I have an existing .net application rendering data in razor, and I would like to display a specific node from an XML string for each record using razor.  But I am not sure how to go about writing it.  There will be 50+ records in the model, so I want to make sure it's efficient.
Each record in the model will have it's own xmldata.  For example:

Model:

```
namespace Project.Web.ViewModels
{  
   public class SampleModel  
   {  
      public int id { get; set; }  
      public string xmldata { get; set; }  
   }  
}
```

xmldata for first record:

```
<content>
  <user>
    <firstname>Jim</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
  </user>
</content>
```

xmldata for second record:

```
<content>
  <user>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Jones</lastname>
  </user>
</content>
```

csHtml:

```
@model Project.Web.ViewModels.SampleModel
@foreach (item in Model) {
   <p><b>ID:</b> @item.id</p>
   <p><b>FirstName:</b> //Add firstname from @item.xmldata here</p>
   <p><b>LastName:</b> //Add lastname from @item.xmldata here</p>
   <br>
}
```

Desired output:

```
ID: 1
FirstName: Jim
LastName: Smith

ID: 2
FirstName: John
LastName: Jones
```

An example of how to write the razor code in cshtml would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `@HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(item.xmldata)` will encode the XML so that it displays as text in the browser rather than being interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks, but I only need specific nodes from the xml, not all of the data.

Comment: No one can give you an example of the how to get dome specific output from some XML source without an example of the source and the required output.

Comment: @BenRobinson - I updated the question to clarify the xml data examples for each record, and added a desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach:

```
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 public class SampleModel
 {
     private XDocument document;

     public int Id {get;set;}

     public string FirstName 
     {
         get { return document.Descendants("firstname").Single().Value; }
     }

     // other properties in the same manner

     // Dynamic
     public string GetData(string fieldName)
     { 
        return document.Descendants(fieldname).Single().Value;
     }

     public SampleModel(){}
     public SampleModel(int id, string xml)
     {
        this.Id = id;
        this.document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
     }


 }
```

and in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Web.ViewModels.SampleModel>
@foreach (item in Model) {
   <p><b>ID:</b> @item.id</p>
   <p><b>FirstName:</b> @item.GetData("firstname")</p>
   <p><b>LastName:</b> @item.GetData("lastname")</p>
   <br>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the xmldata is expected to grow over time.  I would prefer to handle it in razor, as opposed to updating the model each time a node is added, if possible.

Comment: in this case you can use the getdata method i added just now

Comment: alternative you can do everything in a razor codeblock @{} you also would have to include the System.Xml.Linq namespace. however the view is usually only responsible to present the data not convert it